# Navigating from ScrollViewController Content view to another view on stack

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I am trying to navigate from a UIScrollView's content view to another view by using a UIButton.  I do not want to display this other view modally, and pushing the view on the stack is not working for me.

Example:
My Viewcontroller contains a Scrollview that has 2 content views.  Within these content views I would like to push another view onto the stack.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: whoops.  Thanks.  I have edited my question to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: Are you trying to do a simple push with a UINavigationController or do you need a scroll view with different subviews as "pages"?

Comment: I have a navigation controller that contains a scroll view (which has sub views)  I would like to navigate to a view from within one of the sub views.. non modally.

Comment: is the navigation you're looking for like the one of the mail and music apps for example?(I'm asking this to understand if what you really want is a scroll view or if navigation controller with different view controllers , each one with its view, is enough)

Comment: I need to navigate to a custom view from within one of my scrollview content views.  What I have is a game with 2 players.. each player on one content view of the scroll view.  in that content view i need to navigate to another view periodically.. but without using a modal presentation if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's see if I understood well enough your problem.

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *firstPlayerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *secondPlayerView;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

-(UIView *)firstPlayerView
{
    if (!_firstPlayerView) {
        _firstPlayerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        // set up your view as you like and place the button to go to the second player
        // view when you need to.
        // let's suppose that you called that button "goToSecondPlayerViewButton"
        [goToSecondPlayerViewButton addTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(switchPlayer) 
                             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return _firstPlayerView;
}

-(UIView *)secondPlayerView
{
    if (!_secondPlayerView) {
        _secondPlayerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0)];
        // set up your view as you like and place the button to go to the first player
        // view when you need to.
        // let's suppose that you called that button "goToFirstPlayerViewButton"
        [goToFirstPlayerViewButton addTarget:self
                                      action:@selector(switchPlayer) 
                            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return _secondPlayerView;
}

-(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (!_scrollView) {
        _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
        _scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
        [_scrollView addSubview:self.firstPlayerView];
        [_scrollView addSubview:self.secondPlayerView];
        _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height);
        _scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
        _scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        _scrollView.bounces = NO;
        _scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        _scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    }
    return _scrollView;
}

-(void)switchPlayer
{
    if(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, 0, self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
        self.title = @"Second Player";
    } else {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:self.scrollView.bounds animated:YES];
        self.title = @"First Player";
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
    self.title = @"First Player";
}

@end
```

I hope that solves your problem! I haven't tested the code so if you encounter problems just comment and I'll try to help.

Edited : To add a view you just enlarge the scroll view contentSize and add that view as its subview

```
-(UIView *)thirdView
{
    if (!_thirdView) {
        _thirdView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds * 2, self.view.bounds.size.width, 0)];
        // set up your view as you like 
    }
    return _thirdView;
}

-(void)addThirdView
{
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * 3, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.thirdView];
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * 2, 0, self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];
}
```

You can generalize this and set your content size first then have a single method that takes an index as an argument.

```
-(void)scrollToViewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.bounds.size.width * index, 0, self.scrollView.bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.bounds.size.height) 
                                animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: dude.. thanks for putting so much time into helping me out.  I really appreciate it.  This is almost there.. what I am trying to figure out is how to push another view onto the stack, from within the 'firstPlayerView' or 'secondPlayerView' from your example.